# Too few arguments to function call, expected at least 2, have 0

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I wrote the following code:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
//
-(void)testLog;
//
+(void)testLog;
@end
```

```
//===============================
SEL sel = @selector(testLog);
IMP imp = class_getMethodImplementation([TestClass class], sel);
imp();
//===============================
SEL testSel = @selector(testLog);
IMP testImp = class_getMethodImplementation(objc_getMetaClass(class_getName([TestClass class])), testSel);
testImp();
```

[image: Too few arguments to function call, expected at least 2, have 0]

I set the `Enable Strict Checking of objc_msgSend Calls` to NO but still have this error。

[image: Enable Strict Checking of objc_msgSend Calls]

Why is it wrong?

Comment: Has been resolved, modify `objc_msgSend` to YES,  build succeeded!

Answer (score 1):

All Methods take a minimum of two arguments: a reference to the object (or class in the case of a class method) the method is being called on, this is the value of `self` within the method body; and the selector of the method. This is what is missing in your calls.

You can see this in definition of `IMP` given in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime/imp) is:

```
id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...)
```

With the explanation:

> This data type is a pointer to the start of the function that implements the method. This function uses standard C calling conventions as implemented for the current CPU architecture. The first argument is a pointer to self (that is, the memory for the particular instance of this class, or, for a class method, a pointer to the metaclass). The second argument is the method selector. The method arguments follow.

HTH